# onItemClick get position corrdinates (x,y) of the click, android

Tags: android, listview

I am trying to figure out in a listview row at what x position the click (touch) happened.
In the onItemClick handler what is the way to get the x,y coordinates of the click.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

With onClick you can't but if you setup a onTouch listener than from the MotionEvent class you can get x,y event.getY() and event.getX();

Hope this helps.